# Theme according different OS version

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

The theme is not updating according devices(OS), when i used App compact, it changed the text color and in many of the screen not showing text/ cursors. Some of the places the UI is disturbed.
What is the best way to manage theme for for different OS?